# Using GET verb to update in rest api?

Tags: rest, http, http-verbs

I know the use of `http` verbs is based on standard specification. But my question if I use "`GET`" for update operations and write a code logic to update, does it create issues in any scenario? Apart from the standard, what else could be the reason to use these verbs for a specific purpose only?

Comment: Maybe this is applicable? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment

Comment: Yes, lots. The request could be unintentionally triggered because clients assume it's a safe method, it confuses people, if you want to use a request body it may be dropped, it may mess with caches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> my question if I use "GET" for update operations and write a code logic to update, does it create issues in any scenario?

Yes.

A simple example - suppose the network between the client and the server is unreliable; specifically, for a time, HTTP responses are being lost.  A general purpose component (like a web proxy) might time out, and then, noticing that the method token of the request is GET, resend the request a second/third/fourth time, with your server performing its update on every GET request.

Let us further assume that these multiple update operations lead to an undesirable outcome; where do we properly affix blame?

Second example: you send someone a copy of the link to the update operation, so that they can send you a request at the appropriate time.  But suppose you send that link to them in an email, and the email client recognizes the uri and (as a performance optimization) pre-fetches the link, triggering your update operation too early.  Where do we properly affix the blame?

> HTTP does not attempt to require the results of a GET to be safe.  What it does is require that the semantics of the operation be safe, and therefore it is a fault of the implementation, not the interface or the user of that interface, if anything happens as a result that causes loss of property -- [Fielding, 2002](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-tag/2002Apr/0207.html)

In these, and other examples, blame is correctly affixed to your server, because GET has a standardized meaning which include the constraint that the semantics of the request are [safe](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.1).

That's not to say that you can't have side effects when handling a GET request; "hit counters" are almost as old as the web itself.  You have a lot of freedom in your implementation; so long as you respect the uniform interface, there won't be too much trouble.

---

Experience report: one of our internal tools uses GET requests to trigger scheduling; in our carefully controlled context (which is *not* web scale), we get away with it, and have for a very long time.

To borrow your language, there are certainly scenarios that would give us problems; but given our controls we manage to avoid them.

I wouldn't like our chances, though, if requests started coming in from outside of our carefully controlled context.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a decent question. You're asking a hypothetical: is there any value to doing the right *other* than that's we agree to use `GET` for fetching? e.g.: is there value beyond the fact that it's 'semantically nice'. A similar question in HTML might be: "Is it ok to use a `<div>` with an `onclick` instead of a `<button>`? (the answer is no).

There certainly is. Clients, servers and intermediates all change their behavior depending on what method is used. Even if your server can process `GET` for updates, and you build a client that uses this, your browser might still get confused.

If you are interested in this subject, don't ask on a forum; read the spec. The HTTP specification tells you what clients, servers and proxies should do when they encounter certain methods, statuses and headers.

Start at [RFC7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231)